# unexpected behavior using pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am obtaining different results when applying a function using [pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html) vs [pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).

Spark seams to be (incorrectly) modifying an object inplace.

Here is the minimum reproducible example of the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true") \
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()

def func(df_1, df_2):
    # do something with df_1
    # ...
    
    # this shouldn't modify df_2
    print("df_2 before", df_2.values[0], end="\t")
    mask = np.array([True])
    out = df_2["col_1"].astype(str)
    out[mask] = out[mask].astype(float) / 10
    print("df_2 after", df_2.values[0])

    return pd.DataFrame({"out": [out.astype(str).iloc[0]]})


# sample data
second_df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1": ["90"]})

pdf = pd.DataFrame({"x":['0', '1', '2', '3']})
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```

When calling func() using pandas, 'second_df' is not modified

```
_ = pdf.groupby("x").apply(lambda x: func(x, second_df))

#    df_2 before ['90'] df_2 after ['90']
#    df_2 before ['90'] df_2 after ['90']
#    df_2 before ['90'] df_2 after ['90']
#    df_2 before ['90'] df_2 after ['90']
```

But, when calling func() using pyspark, the dataframe 'second_df' gets modified inside func's scope

```
_ = sdf.groupby("x").applyInPandas(lambda x : func(x, second_df), schema="out string").toPandas()

#    df_2 before ['90'] df_2 after [9.0]
#    df_2 before [9.0]  df_2 after [0.9]
#    df_2 before [0.9]  df_2 after [0.09]
#    df_2 before [0.09] df_2 after [0.009]
```

I was expecting to obtain the same results when using pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas and pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply

**Edit:**

I still don't understand this behaviour, but this is a workaround:

```
def func2(x):
    # sample data
    second_df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1": ["90"]})
    return func(x, second_df)

_ = pdf.groupby("x").apply(func2)

_ = sdf.groupby("x").applyInPandas(func2, schema="out string").toPandas()

# df_2 before ['90']      df_2 after ['90']
# df_2 before ['90']      df_2 after ['90']
# df_2 before ['90']      df_2 after ['90']
# df_2 before ['90']      df_2 after ['90']
# df_2 before ['90']      df_2 after ['90']                           (0 + 1) / 1]
# df_2 before ['90']      df_2 after ['90']
# df_2 before ['90']      df_2 after ['90']
# df_2 before ['90']      df_2 after ['90']
```

**Enviroment:**

```
python = 3.8.9
pandas = 1.5.3
numpy = 1.24.2
pyspark = 3.3.1
pyarrow = 11.0.0
```